# "s" character not working on command prompt after bash history completion

Tags: bash

Im using Centos 6.3 and have customised my .bash_profile with the following commands to help with history completion (and colorising the prompt):

```
bind '"\e[A": history-search-backward'
bind '"\e[B": history-search-forward'
bind '"show-all-if-ambiguous on"'
bind '"set completion-ignore-case on"' 

export PS1="[\[\e[32;1m\]\u@\h \[\e[33;1m\]\W\[\]]\[\e[37;1m\]\$ " 
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
shopt -s checkwinsize
```

Now, at the command prompt when I type any word with an 's' character in it, I cannot see the character until I press spacebar or continue typing. How can I fix this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the excess quotation marks from two of the `bind` commands and add the `set` instruction to one of them:

```
bind 'set show-all-if-ambiguous on'
bind 'set completion-ignore-case on'
```